# Azure cloud service and web sites communication lock down

Tags: azure

I have a azure cloud service (a server) where i host a Redis database. I also have a web site hosted in azure web sites. I want the web site to be able to talk to the Redis DB on port 6379. I know I can configure a public endpoint for that port on my server but that would open it for whole Internet. I want it opened only for azure web sites (or even better, only for my web site). How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Azure Web Sites is in an isolation bubble separate from your Cloud Services and there's no way to bridge that gap. Ideally you'd do this by connecting the web site machine to other Azure services via a Virtual Network, but [this FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn133803.aspx#BKMK_VNETandServices) confirms you can't do that right now:

> Can I use Windows Azure websites with Virtual Network?
>
> No. We do not support websites with virtual networks.

Opening Redis up over the internet shouldn't even be considered as it doesn't have the kind of security you'd want out of the box to be opening up its port publicly as it is meant to be co-located with your application, so you really wouldn't want to do that. Never mind the added network overhead which will eat into the performance you expect to get by leveraging something like Redis anyway.

I believe your best bet given your current configuration is to add a Web Role that's part of the same Azure Cloud Service and run your web based application out of that so that it can communicate with worker role. It only requires a little bit of configuration to get this going (i.e. adding an [InternalEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180158.aspx) to the Redis Worker Role). While I realize Web Roles don't offer as frictionless a development model as Web Sites, you have to choose the right tool for the job.

Another option, if you want to setup your Redis on a VM instead of tying it to the Cloud Service directly, is that you can setup a Virtual Network, put the Redis VM on the virtual network and then configure the Cloud Service so that it's part of the same affinity group and add the [`NetworkConfiguration/VirtualNetworkSite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156091.aspx#bkmk_VNSite) configuration section to the Cloud Service's .cscfg.

Which approach makes more sense all depends on how you leverage your Redis instance, but the main benefit of the latter approach is that the Redis instance is not recreated each time you deploy your Cloud Service and, so, any data that's in it will stay available between deployments. Another benefit is if you want to build and leverage a Redis cluster across multiple Cloud Services this enables you to do that.

Comment: Thanks Drew! I think I need read more about the Azure concepts. Right now I have Redis on a VM. But it is hosted as a cloud service (according to my azure portal), a server size M. Do you mean I can run this VM in another way?

Comment: I found a good explanation here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-connect-virtual-machine/

Comment: You *could* leave it running in a WorkerRole if that's how you're running it now and are comfortable with that, however you would need to redefine that worker role so that it's part of the same affinity group as the VPN and obviously add the same NetworkConfiguration/VirtualNetworkSite section to it. Otherwise you can do a straight up VM which even gives you the option of running a Linux version of Redis if that is somehow more attractive to your team.

Comment: I'm a Microsoft guy :) I don't know much about Linux. I now have a Redis fork from Microsoft. Do you know if there are any .net Redis clients that can be used against a Linux Redis server?

Comment: Me too, just thought I'd throw that out there as FYI. :) AFAIK, any Redis client impl should be used against any Redis server impl. The version is all that matters and as long as you use compatible client and server versions you should be gtg.